# "Prendre en charge de distance", "tenir au bord des sentiments"?

Tags: paroles-de-chanson

In this part there are two phrases which i can't find anywhere, from "*Amours Dévouées*" song (Coeur de pirate, from the [*Blonde*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blonde_(C%C5%93ur_de_pirate_album)) album, 2011):

> On ne vit pas au large, mais bien pris en charge
>  de distance,
>   nous, amants séparés
>  Par des docks hantés aux barques
>   amarrées
>  Qui nous tiennent au bord des sentiments
>  [...]

"Mais bien pris en charge de distance" and "Qui nous tiennent au bord des sentiments"

What do they mean?

Comment: I saw the lyrics, it's gonna be weird anyway

Comment: J'ai l'impression que c'est l'équivalent du yaourt, mais en français: des mots au hasard qui ne sont pas vraiment là pour avoir du sens.

Comment: @AnneAunyme C'est un peu l'impression que j'ai eu. Il doit toutefois y avoir un moyen de déchiffrer le message de ces vers

Comment: J'ai beau faire des efforts, ces phrases restent opaques. je rejoins l'avis d'@AnneAunyme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En suivant la connotation maritime :

> Mais bien pris en charge de distance...

... vient après *On ne vit pas au large* :
Nos corps sont séparés, non pas par une mer ou un océan, mais par la distance qu'ils s'imposent, qu'ils prennent en charge, sans s'en rendre compte car

> séparés Par des docks hantés aux barques amarrées.

... il y a des liens qui relient nos 'barques'  à nos vies et  habitudes antérieures à notre rencontre...

> Qui nous tiennent au bord des sentiments.

Sans liberté, celle qui détache nos liens, les amants sont séparés et leurs émotions qui ne peuvent s'épanouir dans la continuité, la mémoire les tient en suspend.